# Jersey @Path annotation mandatory at class level

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a class like:

```
public class TestService {

@Path("/v1/test1/list")
    public Response getTest1() {
}

@Path("/v1/test2/list")
    public Response getTest2() {
}

}
```

If I do not give @Path annotation at Class level, then this class is not recognized as a REST resource, but I cannot give "/v1" Path for this class since there is already another class with @Path("/v1").

What are possible workaround, to make this class to be recognized as a Rest Resource

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Resource classes

A [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation is required to define a *resource class*. Quoting the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html):

> *Root resource classes* are POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) that are annotated with `@Path`, have at least one method annotated with `@Path` or a resource method designator annotation such as `@GET`, `@PUT`, `@POST`, `@DELETE`.

### One possible solution

As already [mentioned by Justas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39242070/1426227), one possible solution is to add the `@Path("")` annotation to the `TestService` class. However, it doesn't smell good:

```java
@Path("")
public class TestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/v1/test1/list")
    public Response getTest1() {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/v1/test2/list")
    public Response getTest2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

### A better solution

I don't know what your project looks like, but instead of having a single class, I would have two classes, designed as following:

```java
@Path("/v1/test1")
public class TestService1 {

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    public Response getTest1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("/v1/test2")
public class TestService2 {

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    public Response getTest2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add empty path `@Path("")` or `@Path("/")`. However, this problem may show that you should design your code differently.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention that @Path needs to be on class level on any documentation I came across. Do you know if this a Jersey specific requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Path` annotation is used to specify the `URI` through which a resource and an API can be accessed. Resource in this case is the `REST` Web service itself. Thus this annotation is present at the class level as well as the method level. It is mandatory to annotate a `REST` Web resource class with the `@Path` annotation. Thus if a user wants to access the 'Countries' through the resource  'HelloWorld' context, then:

Resource at the class level would have `@Path("/")`. This is the default annotation at the class level.
Resource at the API level would have `@Path("Countries")` annotation.
As a best practice, the class-level path annotation should be a noun that qualifies the Web service, and the method-level annotation can be a noun or an action (for example, user and add-user, respectively).

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-space-sdk/13.1/apiref/com.juniper.junos_space.sdk.help/html/reference/spaceannoREST.html